How to Download Points or Areas of Cities and Towns from OSM Using Python, Given Coordinates of an Extension, and Save as Shapefile?
I'm seeking assistance in downloading points or areas data of cities and towns from OpenStreetMap (OSM) using Python and saving them as shapefiles. Specifically, I need to extract this data based on coordinates defining an extension.
I've explored Python libraries like osmnx and overpy, but I'm unsure how to customize them to extract data for specific areas defined by coordinates and save them as shapefiles. My objective is to retrieve data for populated places within a given extension and then save them in the shapefile format.
Could someone provide guidance or examples on how to adapt these libraries to download points or areas data within defined coordinates and save them as shapefiles? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I've explored Python libraries like osmnx and overpy, but I'm unsure how to customize them to extract data for specific areas defined by coordinates and save them as shapefiles. My objective is to retrieve data for populated places within a given extension and then save them in the shapefile format.

This is easily done with OSMnx. Your question is vague so it's hard to give specific guidance. But the OSMnx documentation and examples gallery explain how to retrieve OSM features and save them.
